# Representing positive numbers in first order logic with the structure ($\mathbb{R},+,\cdot$)

Tags: first-order-logic

The problem is to represent (in first order logic) the interval $[0, \infty)$ under the structure $\frak{R}$, whose universe is the real numbers. $\forall$ quantifies the real numbers and $+^{\frak{R}},\cdot^{\frak{R}}$ are their usual meanings (addition, multiplication).

Since this is all nonnegative real numbers, I have this so far:

$\forall v_2 \exists v_1 (v_1 + v_1 = v_1 \land (v_2 = v_1 \lor  ?))$

Where $v_2$ is a number in the interval and $v_1$ is $0$. The "?" is where I want to say "$v_2 > 0$", but I'm not sure how to do this with first order logic using all real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The non-negative real numbers are the squares.

Comment: Wow didn't even think of this! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure you can now finish, but if there is difficulty, I can give the full answer.

Comment: It would just be the $v_1$ such that $\forall v_1 \forall v_2 (v_1 = v_2 \cdot v_2)$ right?

Comment: We need a formula with a free variable $x$. The formula $\exists y(x=y\cdot y)$ works.

Comment: Why is it a $\exists$ in front of $y$ as opposed to a $\forall$?

Comment: Take the positive number $x=3.5$, It is certainly not true that $\forall y(3.5=y^2)$. In fact there are only $2$ values of $y$ such that $3.5=y^2$.

Comment: I am sorry to re-open this, but how to represent interval $(0,\infty)$ in $\mathcal{A} = \langle \mathbb{R}, \cdot \rangle$? What about this $\forall x \exists y ((y = x \cdot x) \to (y = 0))$, is that correct? If not, what's wrong, please?