# Define $\{ - \sqrt 2 \}$ using only $\langle =,+, -, \cdot, 0, 1 \rangle $ on $ \mathbb{R} $

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, real-numbers

On the structure $\mathbb{R}$ (standard real numbers) and signature $\langle =,+, -, \cdot, 0, 1 \rangle $ define the set $\{-\sqrt 2\}$, i.e. find a formula $\varphi$(a), such that $ \{a \in \mathbb{R}; \varphi(a) \} = \{-\sqrt 2\}$.

---

It is clear to me that I can get $\{\sqrt 2, -\sqrt 2 \}$ easily with $\varphi(a) := a \cdot a = 1 + 1$, but since there is no $\leq$, I can't see a way to define just the negative square root. I'm kind of beginning to think it is not possible, but the question is formulated in such a way that it seems to imply that it really is possible.

Comment: You say that there is no $\le$, but I see no $=$ either. In fact, nothing to build a predicate.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy Right, how the question was originally formulated kind of silently assumed it. I changed it so that it is explicit.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/982888/42969

Comment: So I guess that the question essentially boils down to somehow expressing $a<0$ with the zero set of a polynomial.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, this actually helped.

Comment: I am no specialist but I guess that as $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$, you can't separate the two roots.

Comment: @MartinR Yes! I spent too much time thinking about how to solve it with polynomials, but somehow forgot to look up how to define positive numbers, or maybe I did but didn't come across this. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy The symbol $=$ is a primitive logical symbol in first-order logic. It's always present, so it does not need to be specified in the language.